# If I useTSL on my website, do I need to hash password on the client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, password-protection, web-development-server

I'm making a social media web app and I'm hashing password on the server side, sending plain txt password from client-side to the server for hashing.My question is that if i send password as a plain text and use TSL, Is this secure from  MAN IN THE MIDDLE ATTACK?